# Shortest and latest match in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression:

```
\{\{([\S\s]+?)\.$
```

And text:

```
{{system 1}} asdfd{{system2.
```

I need to parse the most shortest match like "system2"

Comment: What do you mean by _shortest_ ?

Comment: @noob I would assume he means smallest match

Comment: Now it parses "system 1}} asdfd{{system2", i need "system2"

Comment: @RedLaser: What does it mean by smallest match in this context ?

Comment: it already works https://regex101.com/r/rH3nV0/1

Comment: You can add greedy `.*` before. Try [`(?s).*{{(.+?)\.`](https://regex101.com/r/xR5eP0/3)

Comment: @unccoder, You should have told us that you are using it in the `replaceAll`. You are, aren't you?

Comment: Try [`System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?s)^.*\\{\\{|\\W*$", ""));`](https://ideone.com/sXwNYO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
\{\{(?!.*\{\{)([\S\s]+)\.
```

Negative lookahead `(?!.*\{\{)` ensures that we match last `{{` in input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vH1yQ9/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
(?<=\{\{)([\S\s]+?)(?=\.$)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rH3nV0/2